# Multiple text nodes in Python's ElementTree? HTML generation

Tags: python, elementtree, html-generation

I'm using ElementTree to generate some HTML, but I've run into the problem that ElementTree doesn't store text as a Node, but as the `text` and `tail` properties of `Element`. This is a problem if I want to generate something that would require multiple text nodes, for example:

```
<a>text1 <b>text2</b> text3 <b>text4</b> text5</a>
```

As far as I can tell there is no way to generate this- am I missing something? Or, is there a better solution for quick and simple HTML generation in Python?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To generate the above string with `ElementTree` you can use the following code.  The trick to this is that the `text` is the very first lot of text before the next element and the `tail` is all the text after the element up to the next element.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.Element("a")
root.text = 'text1 ' #First Text in the Element a
b = ET.SubElement(root, "b")
b.text = 'text2' #Text in the first b
b.tail = ' text3 ' #Text immediately after the first b but before the second
b = ET.SubElement(root, "b")
b.text = 'text4'
b.tail = ' text5'
print ET.tostring(root)
#This prints <a>text1 <b>text2</b> text3 <b>text4</b> text5</a>
```

Comment: "tail is all the text after the element up to the next element." Ah, that's what I didn't realize. Thanks!